# Confusion about using Methods with Parameters

Tags: java

First of all, I just started learning java via tutorials.
So i was following this tutorials. 
I have a question- Why we use Methods with parameters?
Below is the screenshot of the tutorial where there are two classes- Apples.java(Main),Tuna.java . 
Now, in Tuna.java,Why did he put 'String name' in the simpleMessage method?
Can't it be like:

```
public class tuna {
    public void simpleMessage(){
        String name;
        system.out.println("Hello"+name);
    }
}
```

Apples

[image: Apples.java Class]

Tuna

[image: Tuna.java class]

Comment: You are passing a value to the method when you call it. If you just declare it in the method then you can't pass any value to it. For example: `simpleMessage("Manpreet");` will output `Manpreet`...

Comment: Okay. Also is it necessary to declare the variable within the parantheses?

Comment: If you declare it inside the parenthesis it is not a "variable" but a "parameter" to that method. If you declare it inside the method it is a "variable". Yes you must declare parameters inside the parenthesis following the method declaration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't it be like?
>
> ```
> public class tuna {
>     public void simpleMessage(){
>         String name;
>         System.out.println("Hello"+name);
>     }
> }
> ```

Nope, this code will produce an error because local variables must be assigned a value.

And this:

```
public class tuna {
    public void simpleMessage(){
        String name = "Manpreet";
        System.out.println("Hello "+name);
    }
}
```

Will always print the same

```
Hello Manpreet
```

(not very useful, right?)

---

The right way to do it is the one you posted in images, lets see:

In this line you wait for the input of the user:

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

When enter is pressed, what user entered is stored in variable `name` and passed to tuna object via argument in the method

```
tunaObject.simpleMessage(name);
```

The point is, `name` is just the variable name that matches in both classes... but this will work the same:

```
String userName = input.nextLine();
tunaObject.simpleMessage(userName);
```

What you pass here is the value, variable name is lost when arriving to `tuna` object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is declared as a parameter in the method is so you can pass a value to it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Tuna tuna = new Tuna();
    tuna.simpleMessage("Manpreet");
}
```

Output:

> Manpreet

If you declare `name` inside the method then you can't pass anything to it.

```
public void simpleMessage()
{
    String name = "Manpreet";
    system.out.println("Hello"+name);
}
```

In the case above name is being declared in the method so I can populate it inside the method but not by passing a value to it.

In the below example I am passing the value "Manpreet" to the parameter `name`:

`public void simpleMessage(String name)`

`tuna.simpleMessage("Manpreet");`

Comment: `  public class tuna {
    public void simpleMessage(name){
    String name;
    system.out.println("Hello"+name);

    }
    }`      What about this?

Comment: @ManpreetSingh it won't compile...you should try these things in an IDE so you can see what is happening.

Comment: I do, but i really cant find why?

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote would produce a NullPointerException as You only declare your variable. If you use the proposed construct with parameters there will be a value in the variable `name` beacuse it has been passed as a parameter.

Your supposed code would output `Hellonull`beacuse there's no value in your variable.

Answer (score -1):

That string is a parameter to the method. Methods can take parameters, and those parameters become part of the signature of the method, like:

```
public void receiveString(String test)
```

or

```
private int receiveInt(int test)
```

Parameters are used to pass informations between methods. Keep in mind that Java is always pass-by-value (The variable that you pass will not be affected in its original scope).